# Align menu with content in Wordpress using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment

I am trying to left align a menu to the left of the content area using CSS for in wordpress theme for desktop and tablet. https://www.textualhealing.co.uk

The content of the menu is justified left as in the code below the issue is the grid layout being auto sized across the menu

[Inspect view of the siteheader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3zEQ.jpg)

[Desired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0rIx.jpg)

I have tried adjust the column width using the code below. It is working in the inspect view of Chrome but not in Wordpress.

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 560px)  
    {
.main-navigation {
        align-self: flex-start;
    justify-self: flex-start;
      align-content: flex-start;
    }}

@media only screen and (min-width: 560px)  
{
    .masthead
    .site-title
    .site-description
    {
grid-template-columns: 14.5em;
    }}
```

How do i get the menu to left align with the content please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `.site-header` css class' css property as follows instead of auto

```
grid-template-columns: min-content;
```

Then you need to specify min-width for the site title in order to avoid word wrapping

```
.site-title {
   min-width: 2600px;
}
```

It looks like this after these modifications

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi mean what i understand you want navigation go to the left,you have to

```
 grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;


that solve what you desired but if you want to make that better you have to wrap your nav with the content in your html and try like that ;

<div class="container" >
 <div class="logo">My Header</div> 

 <main>

   <nav>
     <ul>
       li{Item $}*4
     </ul>
   </nav>
   <!--Continue your markup -->
 </main>
</div>

So in Css you will apply the gird in the container so logo and every thing will be grid children 
#CSS
.container{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns :200px 1fr; //1fr is like "auto "
grid-template-rows:1fr;
/* & continue styling your nav and all your markup and that is a better way */
}
/////And add your content Markup  ///
this is usefull ? please return back if you have some thing you don't understand , just like friend ("_") goodLuck
```